# SocketException on my asyncserver

Tags: c#, tcp, server-side, serversocket

Okay first let me say, this is my first attempt at writing a client/server software.
My clients is Android handheld devices written in Java and Server is written in C#.

My server implementation is an AsyncSocketServer example taken from the MSDN website which I modify to fit my needs.

**What I achieved:**

Client can connect to server.
Client can send 1st request to server.
Server sends back an answer to the request.

**Not working:**

When client tries to send another request, it all goes bad.

This next line throws "socketException was unhandled" and since I'm new to this server side thing, I have no idea what I'm doing to screw it up.

```
      // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
```

Exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at PlayServer.Network.AsynchronousSocketListener.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) in c:\Users\Unknown\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\Network\TCPServer.cs:line 130
```

My server code:

```
namespace PlayServer.Network
{
    // State object for reading client data asynchronously
    public class StateObject
    {
        // Client  socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        // Received data string.
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public class AsynchronousSocketListener
    {
        // Thread signal.
        public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public static CountdownEvent freeToSend;

        // Instances for interactions
        private static PlayerUI mainW;
        private static MainPlayer player = MainPlayer.Instance;
        private static MessageManager messageHandler = MessageManager.Instance;



        public AsynchronousSocketListener()
        {
           freeToSend = new CountdownEvent(1);
           messageHandler.registerUI(mainW);
           StartListening();
        }

        public static void registerUI(PlayerUI main)
        {
            mainW = main;
        }

        public static void StartListening()
        {
            // Data buffer for incoming data.
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
            // The DNS name of the computer
            // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 5555);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(100);

                while (true)
                {
                    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                    allDone.Reset();

                    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    listener.BeginAccept(
                        new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                        listener);

                    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                    allDone.WaitOne();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();

        }

        public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Signal the main thread to continue.
            allDone.Set();

            // Get the socket that handles the client request.
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = handler;
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }

        public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            String content = String.Empty;

            // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the client socket. 
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            // Read string from client 
            string recievedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
             state.buffer, 0, bytesRead).ToString();

            // Figure what kind of message(Operation) client requested
            string answerFromServer = messageHandler.figureMessageType(recievedMessage);

            // Wait for JSON serialization/de-serialziation to finish and then send a reply to client
            freeToSend.Wait();
            Send(handler, answerFromServer);



            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                    state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
                // more data.
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                {
                    // All the data has been read from the 
                    // client. Display it on the console.
                    Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                        content.Length, content);
                    // Echo the data back to the client.
                    Send(handler, content);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Not all data received. Get more.
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                }
            }

        }


        private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                //handler.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the whole exception and where it occurred.

Comment: I've added the exception in the original post. Thank u

Comment: You are assuming that Receive reads one "message" at a time. TCP does not have a concept of messages. Fix this issue and I'll look again. Consider making everything synchronous. It is not clear that you benefit at all from async IO and it makes stuff very complicated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Can your code tolerate Receive just reading one byte at a time even if more data will be coming? If not it is broken.

Comment: Changed it to synchronous and now it all works way better